# Render 2 at Once - Faster than One?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

Simple question, I'd like to know what would be faster overall:

- have 2 or Blender projects open (same PC) and have both rendering at the same time
- just have one open and let that one have all the GPU to itself

If one has a benefit over the other I'd be very curious to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start multiple jobs at the same time, but they don't render any faster.

In my experience, one will grab most of the resources and the second job will go along at a snails pace until the first finishes.  You also have to worry more about going over the total amount of resources in your machine.  The one advantage is you can start them both and go to bed without having to worry about it.

If you want unattended batch rendering there are services for it, or blender can be set to start a render through the command line; you could create a batch file for multiple jobs.

Comment: Yes, **computer power is limited**. Anything that requires more resources than those available, will result in a slowdown.  Also, rendering on GPU doesn't mean that the CPU is idle. There are plenty of calculations that use the CPU regardless.

Answer (score 3):

**It will strongly depend on your scene and rendering setting.**

---

As some common scenario, GPU's VRAM for example. Let's say we have a scene, there are a lot of particle system, numerous rigging system, some simulation baked data, and animation as well. As a common user, you cannot know how much memory that GPU need **nor Blender itself** until it ask for them.

Having not enough memory to keep thing inside GPU will strongly slow down for rendering process, due to some bandwidth issue. So if the same time you open **two** instance of Blender, they then need to share those resource together, which might cause a more frequently memory swap. Dramatically slow down rendering process, then the answer will be
 **→ "No, slower than 1 instance"**

But in other way, said you got some calculation script inside rendering time, and maybe access outer API for some further calculation, and that *process* can be done by only single process/thread. eg. a simple but calculation intensive Python script without multi-process ability. Than some processor will be spare in rendering time, in this situation, multiple Blender instance can utilize those spare/free resource.

**→ "Yes, faster than 1 instance"**

---

**General speaking**
*Not until you try it, you won't know which one will be faster.*